$P\oplus 1$ complete implies $P$ consistently complete
I am reading Introduction to Lattices and Orders, second edition, by Davey and Priestley. I am trying to prove Lemma 9.4. I did (i) implies (ii), (ii) implies (iii), (iii) implies (iv), but cannot prove (iv) implies (i).
I tried this: let $S$ be consistent. Then $\bigvee_{P\oplus 1} S$ exists. Suppose it is $\top$. Then I don't know where to go. I don't know how to use $S$ being consistent and $P$ being a CPO.

9.4 Lemma. Let $P$ be a CPO. Then the following are equivalent:
(i) $P$ is consistently complete, that is, $\bigvee S$ exists for every consistent set $S$ in $P$;
(ii) $\bigvee S$ exists whenever $S^u\neq \emptyset$;
(iii) $\bigwedge S$ exists whenever $S\neq \emptyset$;
(iv) $P\oplus 1$ is a complete lattice.
Here CPO means $P$ contains $\perp$ and $\bigvee D$ exists for every directed subset $D$ of $P$. A subset $S$ of $P$ is consistent if for every finite subset $F$ of $S$, there exists $z\in P$ such that $z\in F^u$.

Let $D$ be the set of joins, in $P \oplus \mathbf{1}$, of the finite subsets of $S$;
it follows that $\bigvee S = \bigvee D$.
Suppose that $1 \in D$;
then there exists a finite subset $F$ of $S$ such that $\bigvee F = 1$, in contradiction with the fact that $F$ must have an upper bound in $P$.
Hence $1 \notin D$.
Let $x, y \in D$, and let $F_x, F_y \subseteq S$ be finite sets such that $x = \bigvee F_x$ and $y = \bigvee F_y$ (joins in $P \oplus \mathbf1$, because we know they exist there).
Let $z = \bigvee (F_x \cup F_y)$;
then $z \in D$ and $x,y \leq z$;
so we conclude that $D$ is a directed set in $P$ (because $1 \notin D$).
As $P$ is a CPO, there is $d \in P$, such that $d= \bigvee D$.
We conclude that $d = \bigvee S$.

Thank you. It seems that the definition of $D$ is a standard technique. I need to learn that.
